# How to write tests for main() function that does not return anything

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, nose

I'm trying to test the code in the main() but I'm a bit unsure how to go about it since I'm not passing any arguments or even returning anything. For the purposes of the example I've shortened the tree statements in the function..

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to test the logic below?  Also I did google to see if this question had already been asked but I couldn't find it, so if it was apologies did not mean to ask again.

script.py

```
from . import settings


def main():
    if settings.PATHS:  # list containing full paths to a directory of files
        paths = settings.PATHS
        for path in paths:
            data = read_file(path)
            modified_data = do_something_with_the_data_collected(data)
            write_to_new_file(modified_data)
    else:
        logger.warning("There are no files in {}".format(settings.FILES_DIRECTORY))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

tests/file_tests.py

```
import unittest

from module.script import main


class FileManagerTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main_func(self):
        main()  # ?? this is where I am stuck, should I just test 
                # that it logs correctly if certain data exists 
                # in settings file?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You test what it's supposed to *do*, e.g. mock out the things it interacts with and make sure it does so correctly in the appropriate circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Your function *has* inputs - but they are not arguments.  For example, settings.PATHS obviously is an input.  You are receiving more inputs via read_file etc.  Moreover, you also have outputs, namely the data you pass to write_to_new_file.  You will have to find ways to influence the input data and to observe the output data.

I recommend to read a bit about test doubles (stubs, mocks and the like) and how to use them in unit-testing.  This will help you to deal with the dependencies in your code while testing.

And, you can make your life a lot easier if you also learn a bit about designing code for testability.  This can help you to improve the design to remove dependencies or make them easier to handle.